# request from postman is ignored but from swagger is not ignored by jwt in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, swagger

I have configured spring boot and jwt. When I call the /authenticate/login from postman it is ignored as expected and generates a jwt token. When I call the same API from swagger-ui.html the request is not ignored. Instead, it is processed for jwt token and return 401 exceptions.

```
http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()enter code here
                .disable()
                .authorizeReques`enter code here`ts()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger.json").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate/*", "/user/forgotpassword").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
.and()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Beow is my swagger config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("!prod")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enable(true)
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()));
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(null, null, null, null, "Bearer access_token", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER,
                SecurityConstants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, ",");
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Authorization", "Authorization", "header");
    }

}
```

It's the same url from both swagger and postman but different behaviour.
What is causing this weird behaviour?.

Comment: An option to disable security over swagger resources could be: @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");

}

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the difference between the two HTTP requests. Many different ways to go about it, I'm thinking that with spring boot, the simplest thing is to add `logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=
  DEBUG` to your `application.properties` file. 

and if you can supplement your question with the different requests, maybe we can help you spot the difference

Comment: here is the request code from postman:

`POST /signage/v1/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ec2-18-217-112-74.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0f7e85d9-1bde-4a60-9ad7-fd7293346c1a
{"username":"string", "password":"string"}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
`

Comment: And request from chrom (swagger-ui.html)
`curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' -d '{"username":"string",
"password":"string}' 'http://ec2-18-217-112-74.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/signage/v1/login'`

The request going from swagger is not ignored by jwt, where as same request going from postman is ignored and allowed to access the authentication resource.